# pandas(dataframe) select data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Hello guys,

I use dataframe to create two tables(A and B) and both have the same columns.
(1st column is 'ID' and one table might have more than one row with same ID)

I want to create a new table(C) based on A and some rows from B.
If the ID in table B also occur in A then add this row into C.

## My code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

A_ID = [1,2,3,1,2]
A_place = [1,2,3,2,1]

B_ID = [4,2,6]
B_place = [2,2,3]

A_data = {'ID':A_ID,'place':A_place}
A_table = DataFrame(A_data)

B_data = {'ID':B_ID,'place':B_place}
B_table = DataFrame(B_data)

C_table = A_table 

for n in range(len(B_table)): 
  if B_table['ID'][n] in list(A_table['ID']):
    C_table = C_table.append(B_table[n:n+1])
```

## Question:

My question is that is there any other way to do it without using for loop?
I will deal with million's of data and for loop wastes lots of time.

By the way, are there other tools better than pandas to deal with big data?

Thanks your help!!

Comment: You can just filter, like `C_table = B_table[B_table['ID'].isin(A_table['ID'])]`

Comment: It works!! I do a little modify to meet my requirement and it looks like this:
`C_table = A_table.append(B_table[B_table['ID'].isin(A_table['ID'])])`
Is it faster than for loop?

Comment: Oh yeah. it should be must faster than looping.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you're doing it will be more performant to just do:

```
C_table = pd.concat([C_table, B_table[B_table['ID'].isin(A_table['ID'])]])
```

So firstly the inner statement:

```
B_table[B_table['ID'].isin(A_table['ID'])]
```

Filters out the rows in `B_table` where the IDs are not in table `A_table`, as you're simply appending, rather than appending a row(s) at a time which will be slower, just `concat` them to the existing `C_table`

Comment: I did a time test and your solution and the one using append have nearly the same speed.  Thanks your idea anyway!